# How do I solve a problem with Tuples in cplex?

Tags: optimization, tuples, cplex

1. I have used tuples in CPLEX.
2. The error is  Operator not available for dvar int+ +  demand:int,origin:int,destination:int,time:int.
3. How do I solve this?

````
// Set of inputs
int i=...; //set of origins
int j=...; //set of destinations
int t=...;//set of time step

range origins=1..i;
range destinations=1..j;
range time=1..t;

tuple demand {
    int demand;
    int origin;
    int destination;
    int time;   
}

demand dm[origins][destinations][time]=...;

float p=...;

dvar int+ l[origins][destinations][time];
dvar int+ u[origins][destinations][time];

dexpr float cost1= sum(i in origins,j in destinations, t in time)(p*u[i][j][t]);

//Objective Function
minimize cost1;

subject to{

    forall(i in origins, j in destinations, t in time)

        u[i][j][t]== u[i][j][t-1] + dm[i][j][t]- l[i][j][t];        
} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

In

```
u[i][j][t]== u[i][j][t-1] + dm[i][j][t]- l[i][j][t];
```

dm is a tuple but you need a value, not a tuple in the sum so you should write

```
u[i][j][t]== u[i][j][t-1] + dm[i][j][t].demand- l[i][j][t];
```

Plus since you use t-1 as index you should change

```
forall(i in origins, j in destinations, t in time)
```

into

```
forall(i in origins, j in destinations, t in time:(t-1) in time)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. Still have a problem with the data. Just posted the error.

Comment: Hi, you declared dm as demandType dm=...;//Demand of vehicles but dm is a tuple set so you d rather write {demandType} dm=...;//Demand of vehicles

Comment: same question at https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=56188f81-9d2e-46af-a880-98d9047a4f28&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer#bm56188f81-9d2e-46af-a880-98d9047a4f28

Answer (score 0):

````
int i=...; //set of origins
int j=...; //set of destinations
int t=...;//set of time step

range origins=1..i;
range destinations=1..j;
range time=1..t;

tuple demandType {
int demands;
int origins;
int destinations;
int time;
}

demandType dm=...;//Demand of vehicles


float p=...;//Penalty cost 

dvar int+ l[origins][destinations][time];//numbers of vehicles from origin i to destination j during t
dvar int+ u[origins][destinations][time];//unmet demand from origin i to destination j at the end of t

dexpr float cost1= sum(i in origins,j in destinations, t in time)(p*u[i][j][t]);

//Objective Function
minimize cost1;

subject to{
constraint1:
forall(i in origins, j in destinations, t in time:(t-1) in time)
u[i][j][t]== u[i][j][t-1] + dm.demands- l[i][j][t];

} ```

The model looks fine but the error is from the data file. 
dm = { <19, 1,1,1>, <17, 2,1,1>, <18, 2,1,2>};
Data item "19" unexpected for "Demand[][destinations][time]".
````